# How To Hide JSON API

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application and I'm pulling data with a simple json api. I'm storing the API on hosting and anyone with the url can access it. How do I prevent this and hide it better?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apache server, then find the .htaccess file on root path, you can hide the directory listing by using the below. Just copy and paste it into your .htaccess file:

```
Options All -Indexes
```